# Product title alignment

Tags: html, css, image, line, product

The e-commerce website built in PHP. In the product listing page the product and names do not line up straight. How can i fix this? Added some script I hope this will help. I have added image height the but the image quality is not good.

[image]

HTML:

```css
<script>

/* -- product list images -- */
.product-image img.attachment-shop_catalog,
.product-image img.attachment-shop_single,
.product-image img.attachment-shop_thumbnail {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%; }

.product-image {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden; }

.product-image .front-image {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto; }

.product-image .front-image img {
  min-width: 99.9%;
  max-width: 101% !important;
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
  display: block; }

.product-image .back-image img {
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
  display: block;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden; }

.product-image:hover .back-image img {
  opacity: 1; }

</script>
```

```html
<li class="product-small  grid1 grid-normal">
       <div class="inner-wrap">
        <a href="eyewear_details.php?Id=<?php echo $Frame_id?>">
         <div class="product-image hover_fade_in_back">
          <div class="front-image">
                                            <?php if($Color1Image!="" && file_exists(FRAME_IMAGES_FRONT.$Color1Image)):?>
                                            <img width="247" height="116" alt="ete thecle-cygne" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="<?php


                                            echo PHP_THUMB_PATH_FRONT.urlencode($Color1Image).IMAGE_PROPERTY5;

                                                ?>">
                                            <?php else:
                            echo '<img width="247" height="116" alt="ete thecle-cygne" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="no-image-icon-11.png" style="
    height: 90px !important;"/>';
                                           
                            </div>
         </div><!-- end product-image -->
        </a> 
        <div class="info style-grid1">
         <div class="text-center">
        
         <a href="eyewear_details.php?Id=<?php echo $Frame_id?>"><p class="name"><?php echo $FrameName?></p></a>
         </div><!-- text-center -->
         <div class="clear"></div> 
        </div><!-- end info --> 
       </div> <!-- .inner-wrap -->
      </li><!-- li.product-small -->
```

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: How can we tell with any example of the HTML and CSS?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: What you have posted there is not the real code. For instance, the CSS is in between <script> tags.

Comment: As this is an HTML/CSS issue it is often beneficial to provide the HTML that is sent to the browser instead of PHP. As it is your code is hard to read. Where is the closing PHP tag for `<?php else:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below approach for it

```css
img {
   max-width: 100%;
  }
  .main {
   width:300px;
   display: inline-flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-flow: column nowrap;
   padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="image">
   <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/A/Y/O/m/o/N/placeholder-hi.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="imageName">
   <a href="">Product name</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="image">
   <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/prince-of-stride-alternative/images/1/14/Placeholder_person.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160220192514" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="imageName">
   <a href="">Product name</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="image">
   <img src="https://www.med.unc.edu/tarc/images/person%20placeholder.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="imageName">
   <a href="">Product name</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It is more helpful to others if you give some small explanation of what you have done.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz i think you don't read comments, please read comment then advice, because when css answer is giving by someone is the complete explanation by his running example code, so i think this approach is much better to helpful to other community members if they know about css.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css `flex property` for it in css or use `position:absolute; bottom:0px; width:100%; left:0px;` to product name.

Answer (score 0):

Set the same height for all product images.

Comment: Whilst this may be a good guess, there is no possible way to know without further information, and code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `position: absolute; top: auto; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` along with bootstrap class `img-thumbnail` for responsiveness.
I am using images of different size with labels.
I hope this will help.
[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Asif92/nd2fqnv6/)

Answer (score -1):

use tables and place the image name in different row

Comment: Sound's like a bad idea to me. Any responsive design is now gone with tables. Accessibility will be a nightmare. Honestly, we need more information to work out what is going on.